# MySQL Join and Subqueries

Tags: mysql

I currently have the following tables:

Case_Workflows

```
case_id (PK)  |  work_id (PK)  |    date
     1        |     1          |  2011-12-12
     1        |     4          |  2011-12-13
     2        |     6          |  2011-12-18
```

Workflows

```
  work_id (PK)  |  status_id
     1          |     1
     2          |     1
     3          |     1
     4          |     2
     5          |     2
     6          |     3
```

Statuses

```
  status_id (PK)  |   title
     1            |     abc
     2            |     def
     3            |     ghi
```

What I am attempting to do is pull a count of the total number of cases with a specific status such as 'abc'. The snag is that each case can have multiple workflows and I only want the single most recent one for each case.

The end result should be:

Status: abc - Count: 2

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(cases.case_id) as countNum  
FROM $this->_caseTable  
JOIN case_workflows 
  ON cases.case_id = cases_workflows.case_id  
JOIN workflows 
  ON cases_workflows.workflow_id = workflows.workflow_id  
JOIN statuses 
  ON workflow.status_id = statuses.status_id
WHERE cases.date > '2011-12-12'
AND cases.date <= '2011-12-18'
```

What I am unsure on is how to first select the latest work_id for each case, and then grabbing its status_id to match it to a WHERE clause such as `WHERE statuses.title = 'abc'`

Comment: Why Status for abc is "Count: 2" and not 1? `case_id=1` seems to have latest `work_id=6` and thus `title='def'` and not `'abc'`

Comment: Apologies, you are indeed correct. Edited :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as countNum  
FROM $this->_caseTable  
JOIN workflows 
  ON workflows.workflow_id =  
     ( SELECT workflow_id 
       FROM cases_workflows AS mcwf
       WHERE mcwf.case_id = cases.case_id
       ORDER BY date DESC 
       LIMIT 1
     )
JOIN statuses 
  ON workflow.status_id = statuses.status_id
WHERE cases.date > '2011-12-12'
  AND cases.date <= '2011-12-18'
  AND statuses.title = 'abc'
```

Comment: almost there, I've updated the main post with some different case_workflow data that I'm using. If I use the query you made and search title 'ghi' I correctly get 1 result, if I search 'abc' I correctly get 0 results (at is has since been updated). When I search 'def' I get a count of 2, one for the correct latest row and one for the original outdated row. It does the same if I add another update to case_id 2 for example. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't understand how you get 2 rows when searching for `'def'` with the data you are showing.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now. Correcting. There was no need for the (first) `case_workflows` join.

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm understanding here, you need to add statuses.title to your SELECT clause, and then add a GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT statuses.title, COUNT(cases.case_id) as countNum  
FROM $this->_caseTable  
JOIN (SELECT case_id, work_id, max(date) 
      FROM case_workflows 
      GROUP BY work_id 
      WHERE case_id = cases.case_id) cw 
  ON cases.case_id = cw.case_id  
JOIN workflows 
  ON cw.workflow_id = workflows.workflow_id  
JOIN statuses 
  ON workflow.status_id = statuses.status_id
GROUP BY statuses.title
WHERE cases.date > '2011-12-12'
AND cases.date <= '2011-12-18'
```

Comment: The main problem is the status of a case is determined by the latest 'workflow log' as seen in the first table structure. Old workflow logs aren't deleted as they contain important information on past milestones. Somewhere in there the query will need to select only the latest workflow entry for each individual case

Comment: Edit made...give it a shot once.  I based my "most-recent" workflow on date.  In-theory, it would also have the highest work_id too, right?  I suppose either or would work then.